# How to calculate time duration for the continuous variables having same value in R

Tags: r

---

I want to calculate time duration in green, amber, red color relatively in each traffic cycle for a traffic light(column `sg.0` in my example data), for example to count all the time length from the first green status to the last green status in every cycle, how could I do that?
Data.frame looks like as following:

```
 time sg. 0
1   2014-09-01 00:00:12.0 green
2   2014-09-01 00:00:13.5 green
3   2014-09-01 00:00:30.0 amber
4   2014-09-01 00:00:30.0 amber
5   2014-09-01 00:00:31.5 amber
6   2014-09-01 00:00:32.0 amber
7   2014-09-01 00:00:32.2 amber
8   2014-09-01 00:00:33.5 amber
9   2014-09-01 00:00:33.0   red
10  2014-09-01 00:00:35.0   red
11  2014-09-01 00:00:35.2   red
12  2014-09-01 00:00:37.0   red
13  2014-09-01 00:00:41.0   red
14  2014-09-01 00:00:42.0   red
15  2014-09-01 00:00:42.2   red
16  2014-09-01 00:00:43.0   red
17  2014-09-01 00:00:44.7   red
18  2014-09-01 00:00:44.2   red
19  2014-09-01 00:00:45.5   red
20  2014-09-01 00:00:47.0   red
21  2014-09-01 00:00:48.7   red
22  2014-09-01 00:00:49.7   red
23  2014-09-01 00:00:49.7   red
24  2014-09-01 00:00:49.9   red
25  2014-09-01 00:00:50.9 green
26  2014-09-01 00:00:50.0 green
27  2014-09-01 00:00:52.0 green
28  2014-09-01 00:00:53.0 green
29  2014-09-01 00:00:54.0 green
30  2014-09-01 00:00:55.0 green
31  2014-09-01 00:00:55.0 green
32  2014-09-01 00:01:02.0 green
33  2014-09-01 00:01:03.7 green
34  2014-09-01 00:01:05.7 green
35  2014-09-01 00:01:07.0 green
```

The original data :

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1409518812, 1409518813.6, 1409518830, 
1409518830.1, 1409518831.6, 1409518832, 1409518832.2, 1409518833.6, 
1409518833, 1409518835, 1409518835.3, 1409518837, 1409518841, 
1409518842, 1409518842.3, 1409518843, 1409518844.8, 1409518844.2, 
1409518845.6, 1409518847, 1409518848.7, 1409518849.7, 1409518849.8, 
1409518849.9, 1409518850.9, 1409518850, 1409518852, 1409518853, 
1409518854, 1409518855, 1409518855.1, 1409518862, 1409518863.8, 
1409518865.8, 1409518867, 1409518868, 1409518870.7, 1409518870.3, 
1409518884, 1409518884.2, 1409518884.3, 1409518884.5, 1409518890, 
1409518942, 1409518942.1, 1409518943.7, 1409518943.3, 1409518944.9, 
1409518944, 1409518945, 1409518947, 1409518949.5, 1409518949.6, 
1409518953, 1409518954, 1409518957.8, 1409518957.2, 1409518961, 
1409518961.1, 1409518961.2, 1409518962.2, 1409518962.3, 1409518964, 
1409518965, 1409518966, 1409518967, 1409518967.1, 1409518974, 
1409518975.8, 1409518977.8, 1409518979, 1409518980, 1409519068, 
1409519068.1, 1409519068.7, 1409519070, 1409519071, 1409519073, 
1409519073.8, 1409519081, 1409519082, 1409519083.3, 1409519083.8, 
1409519084.7, 1409519086, 1409519087.6, 1409519089.2, 1409519089.3, 
1409519091, 1409519091.1, 1409519091.6, 1409519092, 1409519092.1, 
1409519093, 1409519094, 1409519094.5, 1409519095, 1409519095.1, 
1409519103, 1409519104), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `sg. 0` = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("amber", "green", "red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
"sg. 0"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to MrFlick's approach, you can use `rle` to first generate an indicator for each colour cycle and then use this to calculate duration.

```
# If you want to calculate the time within each colour
r <- rle(as.numeric(dat$sg.0))
r$values <- seq_along(r$values)
dat$id <- inverse.rle(r)

(a <- aggregate(time ~ sg.0 + id, dat, function(i) diff(as.numeric(range(i)))))
#    sg.0 id time
#1  green  1  1.6
#2  amber  2  3.6
#3    red  3 16.9
# ...

# Use a similar approach, if the cycle is for each green/amber/red
r <- rle(as.numeric(dat$sg.0))
r$values <- rep(seq_along(r$values), each=3, length=length(r$values))
dat$cycle <- inverse.rle(r)

 (b <- aggregate(time ~ cycle, dat, function(i) diff(as.numeric(range(i)))))
#  cycle  time
#1     1  37.9
#2     2 111.2
#3     3 132.3
#4     4   9.0
```

**EDIT** added `as.numeric` to aggregate function call to consistently report in seconds

Comment: Thanks for the considerate answer, the only problems is for the complete sequence of green/amber/red phases, this unit is not unique, the unit of values which are less than one minutes is second, while the values which more than one minutes are converted to minutes.

Comment: Thanks, you're quite right - i missed that. I have made a small edit.

Comment: Hi, @user20650. Sorry to disturb you,  I just realised I had a mistake to understand this problem. The time duration should be from the earliest time of current color to the earliest time of next color.  But I cannot come up with a way to change your solution, can you give a hand?

Comment: Hi again @Chenlu; using the first `rle` method to calculate  `id`: you can then extract the first value of each light change with `(a <- aggregate(time ~ sg.0 + id, dat, '[', 1 ))` and then calculate the time differences with `a$diff <- c(0, as.numeric(diff(a$time)))`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to first identify each color cycle uniquely, then you can collect stats for each of those groups. You can find the cycle with

```
cycle<-cumsum(c(FALSE, dd[-1,2] != dd[-nrow(dd),2]))
```

(assuming your data.frame is named `dd`). Then you can find the duration from the beginning to end with

```
tapply(dd[,1], interaction(dd[,2], cycle, drop=T), function(x) diff(range(x)))
```

which gives

```
green.0 amber.1   red.2 green.3 amber.4   red.5 green.6 amber.7   red.8 green.9 
    1.6     3.6    16.9    40.0     2.9    16.2    17.8     2.0    23.5     9.0
```

Or if you meant a cycle as in a gree/amber/red cycle, you could do

```
cycle<-cumsum(c(dd[1,2]!="green", dd[-1,2] == "green" & dd[-nrow(dd),2] !="green"))
tapply(dd[,1], cycle, function(x) as.double(diff(range(x)), units="mins"))
```

which gives

```
        0         1         2         3 
0.6316667 1.8533333 2.2050000 0.1500000
```