# How to calculate the time duration until the value in one column is changed using R?

Tags: r

I asked a similar question [How to calculate time duration for the continuous variables having same value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023994/how-to-calculate-time-duration-for-the-continuous-variables-having-same-value-in) and got great solutions. But I had a mistake to understand and describe this question. Actually the correct result should be the calculating the time duration of current color until the color changes to other one, rather than the time duration from the first time to the last time with same color.

```
 time sg. 0
1   2014-09-01 00:00:12.0 green
2   2014-09-01 00:00:13.5 green
3   2014-09-01 00:00:30.0 amber
4   2014-09-01 00:00:30.0 amber
5   2014-09-01 00:00:31.5 amber
6   2014-09-01 00:00:32.0 amber
7   2014-09-01 00:00:32.2 amber
8   2014-09-01 00:00:33.5 amber
9   2014-09-01 00:00:33.0   red
10  2014-09-01 00:00:35.0   red
11  2014-09-01 00:00:35.2   red
12  2014-09-01 00:00:37.0   red
13  2014-09-01 00:00:41.0   red
14  2014-09-01 00:00:42.0   red
15  2014-09-01 00:00:42.2   red
16  2014-09-01 00:00:43.0   red
17  2014-09-01 00:00:44.7   red
18  2014-09-01 00:00:44.2   red
19  2014-09-01 00:00:45.5   red
20  2014-09-01 00:00:47.0   red
21  2014-09-01 00:00:48.7   red
22  2014-09-01 00:00:49.7   red
23  2014-09-01 00:00:49.7   red
24  2014-09-01 00:00:49.9   red
25  2014-09-01 00:00:50.9 green
```

So for this fragment of data, this result for separate color(red/green/amber) is like as following :

```
green 18.0
amber 3.0
red   17.9
...
```

I realised I was wrong to deal with this issue, but I have no idea that how to correct. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: How about converting all times into `numeric` (just for ease of operation) and doing `rle(data[,3])` where I'm assuming the third column is your colors? `rle` will tell you the transition points; then grab the corresponding time values and subtract.

Comment: @Carl: One can do arithmetic just fine on `POSIXct` types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  True enough; it just hurts my head sometimes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible approach using the `data.table` package. In general, we will create a lagged variable using its `shift` function and create an index using its `rleid` function (so `green` won't be grouped together).

```
library(data.table)
# If time is already of `POSIXct` class, you will not need to convert it again
setDT(df)[, `:=`(time = as.POSIXct(time), 
                 ltime = shift(as.POSIXct(time), 1L, type = "lead"),
                 indx = rleid(sg.0))][, ltime[.N] - time[1], .(sg.0, indx)]
#     sg.0 indx        V1
# 1: green    1 18.0 secs
# 2: amber    2  3.0 secs
# 3:   red    3 17.9 secs
# 4: green    4   NA secs
```

Comment: Nice other than having to jump into a "not quite ready for prime time" package.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, yeah... but those awesome functions are nowhere to be found :)

Comment: I used the data.table package, but there is an error :"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "shift""

Comment: @Chenlu - did you install Rtools [if you are on Windows] ? What is the version number of the data.table package that you now installed?

Comment: The version is of data.table is 1.9.4. I am using R studio server which is linux,  it failed to install devtools, so I am trying to solve it. @Henk

Comment: @Chenlu - David said you needed to install the development version, that is 1.9.5.

Comment: @Chenlu, did you follow the link I've posted??

Comment: Yes, I followed it, but it failed to install devtools package before the first step when I used R studio sever. Then I did it on the local R studio. Thank you for this solution @David.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here's some fake data which I've converted from 'time' format.

```
xtime<-1:100 + runif(100)/5
xseq<-sample(c(4,5,6),20,rep=T)
# add a bit to get to 100 -- this depends on the seed you get for the random samples
xseq<-c(xseq,8)

xcol<-vector()
for ( j in xseq) {
xcol <- c(xcol,rep(sample(c('red','green','blue'),1),times=j))
}

tran <- rle(xcol)

transwitch <- c(1,cumsum(tran$lengths))
deltatime<-vector()
for (j in 1: length(transwitch)) deltatime[j] <- xtime[(transwitch[j+1])]-xtime[transwitch[j]]
# check part of the results...

deltatime[1:5]
```